# Same CSS gives different results on non-chromium browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, chromium

My `CSS` is giving out different results on different browsers especially on `non-chromium` browsers like `Firefox` while results are regular on `chromium-based` browsers like `Google Chrome` and `Opera`.
I understand that it is a browser-compliance issue. How do I deal with it ?

### HTML

```
<div class="login-username">
    Email or Number
        <br> <input type="text" autofocus>
 </div>

<div class="login-radio">
   <input type="checkbox"/>Keep me logged in
 </div>

<div class="login-password">
    Password
    <br><input type="password"><br>
    <a href="#">Forgotten your password?</a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.login-username {
    position: fixed;
    left:60%;
    top: 2%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-size: 11px;
}

.login-radio {  
    font-size: 11px;
    position: fixed;
    left:61%;
    top: 7%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Raleway';   
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.login-radio input{
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.login-password {
    position: fixed;
    left:74%;
    top: 2%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline;
}

.login-password a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 7.3%;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    left: 75%
}
```

On Chromium-based Browsers - [image: Chromium-based browsers]

On FireFox (Non-Chromium) - [image: On FireFox (Non-Chromium)]

Comment: it is probably because of the user agent stylesheet used by the browsers. they are "default styles". notice the differences between `<input>`s, you should apply reset styles like `width:??px` and `margin:0; padding:0` to give a more uniform result

Comment: I am using `normalize.css`. Is that of any help ?

Comment: yes, i'm not too sure because i personally don't use that. but google said yes.

Comment: Any possible way with which I can specifically target those non-chromium firefox like browsers and fix it ?

Comment: `@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .selector {
    color:lime;
 }`
}

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should reset stylesheets, to reduce browser differences(line heights, margins and font sizes) and so on, it could be reset.css, normalize.css and then just apply yours styles

Otherwise here is the example how different elements of form looks like in diff browsers: 
http://medialize.github.io/ally.js/tests/focus-outline-styles/index.html

Comment: Could you please add wrappers and create http://jsfiddle.net/ ? I'll try to help there